# Посоветуйте python API для транскрипции слов из разных языков

Tags: python, текст, text-to-speech, nltk

Попробовал очень много апишек и пакетов ([googletrans](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans), [pysle](https://github.com/timmahrt/pysle), [epitran](https://github.com/dmort27/epitran), [phomenizer](https://github.com/bootphon/phonemizer)), но либо эффект есть только для европейских языков, либо его нет вообще ([googletrans](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/175)), либо для реально хорошей функциональности надо дополнительно установить несколько программ, что-то подобавлять в path и т. п. (слишком много действий для потенциальных пользователей моих скриптов).

При этом в Интернете есть куча сайтов типа https://easypronunciation.com/en/persian-phonetic-transcription-converter#phonetic_transcription, где нужная функциональность откуда-то присутствует. Также я видел несколько браузерных расширений для того же самого, но не могу найти API, которым они пользуются.

[мой вопрос на обычном stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61987529/how-to-get-pronunciation-phonetics-of-text-not-speech-only-text/61987661?noredirect=1#comment109643957_61987661)

Comment: ipapy...........

Comment: это не совсем то) там просто какие-то вещи про символы IPA, а не  конвертация в эти символы с разных языков

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install googletrans

from googletrans import Translator
```

Comment: так я же написал, что эта штука не работает, не дает произношения по факту